# Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header and HTTP to HTTPS redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I'm attempting to speed up my site and I'm getting the "Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header" and a redirect chain from the http to https versions of the site. Searched high and low, found lots of content around it but have not been able to fix my issue. Have attempted to modify my .htaccess file but no luck. Here's what I have:

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^blockx\.co\.nz$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

If someone could shed some light on what I'm doing wrong, that would be greatly appreciated! My site is currently taking 4s to load, which is way too lonjg